# Protractor - logout from page in afterAll() section

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

I have a lot of jasmine-based tests in different files, each of them defined in format, like

```
describe(... {
   it(...)
   it(...)
....
})
```

I need to perform a log out from the application after the end of the test (end of describing) and log in at the start of each test.

So, I do it accordingly in the beforeAll and afterAll instructions.

```
describe(... {
   beforeAll(async function() {
      await login();
   })

   afterAll(async function() {
      await logOut();
   })

   it(...)
   it(...)
....
})
```

However, the next test couldn't make a login. The following error in my console:

```
Failed: javascript error: document unloaded while waiting for result
      (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.92)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

But if add something, like browser.sleep() after logout then will work.

Looks like when the new test started the logout action from previous test not performed fully.

Is there some correct way (nor browser.sleep) to check until angular page loaded and stable before making a login after logout?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: instead of using the `async/await` in the `beforeAll` and `afterAll`, try to use the `done` callback. For example: `afterAll(function(done) { logOut().then(() => { done(); })})`

Comment: Unfortunately no, this approach leads to the same problem with the same error.

Comment: According to the Jasmine documentation (https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) you would expect that your implementation is correct and should be possible since Jasmine version 2.7.

Comment: Maybe you are not waiting correctly until page is loaded before you start your tests. If this is correct, can you show Login/logout implementation? It seems like you are not waiting correctly in your own functions.

Comment: have you tried waitForAngular() before performing logout?